# Removing a directory containing a file using find

Tags: find, rm, mv

I'm searching a list of directories for certain files and I want to delete the directory that the file is in.

This is what I'm trying:

```
find /converter/storage/unmatched/ -size -4b -name '*.mp3' -execdir mv -b `dirname {}` /converter/storage/smallfiles/ \;
mv: cannot move `.' to `/converter/storage/smallfiles/.'
```

I'm attempting to move it first just to prove to myself that it can be done without trashing unintended files. How do I move or delete the containing directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command won't work as expected for several reasons:

1. bash evaluates `` ​`dirname {}`​ `` *before* the find command gets executed.

   This can be solved by invoking bash to evaluate the output of the `dirname` command
2. The `-execdir` changes to the directory of the found file before executing the command.

   Therefore, even with proper syntax, `dirname {}` will always be `.`.
3. Since find is going through all files inside all directories (rather than the directories itself), moving the directory that's currently being processed may cause unexpected behavior.

   I don't know find well enough to go into details, but the following example should illustrate it.

   ```
   $ find data -type f -printf "  %p" ; echo
     data/1/b  data/1/a  data/2/b  data/2/a
   $
   $ find data -type f -exec bash -c ' \
   > echo -n "  "mv `dirname {}` backup/
   > ' \; ; echo
     mv data/1 backup/  mv data/1 backup/  mv data/2 backup/  mv data/2 backup/
   $
   $ find data -type f -exec bash -c '
   > echo -n "  "mv `dirname {}` backup/; mv `dirname "{}"` backup/
   > ' \; ; echo
     mv data/1 backup/  mv data/1 backup/
   mv: cannot stat `data/1': No such file or directory
   ```

   After moving the directory `data/1`, find keeps processing its contents. This causes an error message since find executes the `mv` for every file in `data/1`, but works well otherwise. When it finishes processing `data/1`, find gets "lost" somehow.
4. While find handles all possible characters with special meaning properly if `{}` occurs as a plain argument to find, the commands in example 3 will fail to execute properly if, e.g., a space occurs in a path. To avoid this, both the argument output of `dirname` have to be quoted.

   Using `` mv "`dirname "{}"`" `` (or `mv "$("{}")"`, which is more legible) will work well with spaces, but it can lead to disastrous consequences in general<sup>1</sup>.
5. `mv -b` cannot backup directories, only files.

As you found out yourself, problem 3 only occurs if you to try to *move* the directory, but not if you, e.g., remove it. Therefore, an easy and safe solution to problem 3 (that fixes problem 5 in the process) is moving the matching directories into a zip file.<sup>2</sup>

Problem 4 can be solved by passing `{}` as an argument to bash and accessing it as `$0`.

The command

```
find /converter/storage/unmatched/ -type f -size -4b -name '*.mp3' \ -exec bash -c ' \
  zip -0mqr smallfiles.zip "$(dirname "$0")"\
' {} \;
```

will work as expected, although it will still generate error messages when trying to move a directory more than once.

A somehow cleaner approach (i.e., without error messages) would be to use `find -depth -type d` to go through the directories themselves.<sup>3</sup>

For each directory, we can use

```
find "$0" -maxdepth 1 -type f -size -4b -name '*.mp3' -printf 1 -quit
```

to print *1* if and only if it should get removed<sup>4</sup>, and test (`[`) to check if find printed *1*.

The command

```
find /converter/storage/unmatched/ -depth -type d -exec bash -c ' \
  [ $(find "$0" -maxdepth 1 -type f -size -4b -name '*.mp3' -printf 1 -quit) ] \
  && echo zip -0mqr smallfiles.zip "$0"\
  ' {} \;
```

will have to desired effect.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> If the name of a directory inside *unmatched* consists, e.g., of a single newline character, `"$(dirname "{}")"` will evaluate to `unmatched` and `$(dirname {})` will evaluate to `.` (i.e., the folder your executing the command from)!</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Even without compressing the files, this will take considerably longer that just (re)moving them if the files are big. Since your destination folder is called *smallfiles*, I suspect this won't be an issue.</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> The -depth` switch makes find process each directory's contents before processing the directory itself. This avoids the error messages we got with the first approach.</sub>

<sub><sup>4</sup> The `-quit` switch makes find stop after finding the first match. It's not strictly necessary, but it might speeds things up a bit.</sub>

Comment: Running with echo it outputs the correct instructions, but running it with `mv` only moves a single directory then complains `No such file or directory`. I'm fairly sure this has something to do with my (mis)understanding of find. Are you able to point me in the right direction here?

Comment: The `mv` commands can cause a lot of error messages, since find may try to remove a directory once for every matching file in it (or in its subdirectories). This is certainly sub-optimal, but – unless I'm missing something – it should move all matching directories.

Comment: It didn't - only a single directory. Changing to an `rm` did the trick without errors, which is what I was aiming for anyways. Thanks for the hand. I really need to figure out order of substitution/evaluation.

Comment: I have an hypothesis (that I'll verify tomorrow): After processing the first matching directory, find – unaware that the directory has been moved – advances to its parent folder (`smallfiles`). Without any more files to process, it exits immediately.

Comment: `no such file or directory` occurs for every successive file that matched though. For 100 folders, it moves one, then errors 99 times.

Comment: I'm still not sure about the details, but zipping the files instead of moving them seems to be good workaround. I've also added a little more information.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the extra detail you went into also.